# Selecting item from dropdown box in internet explorer using vba

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

The below values represent a combobox / combo-list on a website. I am trying to select item #3 from the drop down using VBA. I have tried several things, but I have had no luck selecting said item. I have tried looking for solutions on Google and the Stack but haven't found anything that seems to work.

```
<DIV id=ext-gen256 class="x-layer x-combo-list x-combo-list-small"  style="FONT-SIZE: 10px; HEIGHT: 92px; WIDTH: 113px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 744px;       Z-INDEX: 12007; TOP: 235px; VISIBILITY: visible">

<DIV id=ext-gen257 class=x-combo-list-inner style="HEIGHT: 90px; WIDTH: 111px">

<DIV class="x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30829" viewIndex="0">Select</DIV>
<DIV class="x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30829" viewIndex="1">Item 1</DIV>
<DIV class="x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30829" viewIndex="2">Item 2</DIV>
<DIV class=""x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30829" viewIndex="3">Item 3</DIV>
<DIV class="x-combo-list-item" _nodup="30829" viewIndex="4">Item 4</DIV></DIV></DIV>
```

I have used several variatons of the below code to try and select the item in question (i.e item #3), or use .value = "Item 3", but this does not work. The text value in the input/droupdown box changes to the right value but for some reason the form won't apply the filter accordingly. However, if I physically type "Item 3" inside then input/droupdown box then submit the form, it works.

```
Dim inputE As MSHTML.HTMLHtmlElement
Set inputE = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("x-combo-list-item")
If inputE.innerText = "Item 3" Then
    inputE.Select
End If
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated. I have been trying to figure this out, literally, for days.

Comment: `inputE` is a *collection* of items, not a single item.  You need to loop over that collection (you can use `For Each`) and check each element's `innerText`: when you find a match then run the element's `Click` event.

Comment: I believed I tried that approach a few times before. Would you mind providing an example? I may have gotten the syntax wrong :/

Comment: *it doesn't seem to work*: describe what happens: error message? on which line?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim el As MSHTML.HTMLHtmlElement, els

Set els = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("x-combo-list-item")

For each el in els

    If el.innerText = "Item 3" Then
        Debug.Print el.innerText
        el.click
        Exit For
    End If

Next el
```

Comment: I tried this and received a runtime 438 error "Object doesn't support this property or method (line: set els = ..) :/

Comment: Difficult for me to suggest anything without some way for me to test.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to do this. What a pain this was lol.

```
Dim inputElement0 As MSHTML.HTMLButtonElement
Set inputElement0 = IE.document.getElementById("ext-gen255")

    If inputElement0.HasChildNodes = True Then
    MsgBox True
    Else
    MsgBox False
    End If
```

This helped me identify which of the elements had children (which, as I figured the object name suggested, could constitute sub items in the drop down) then..

```
inputElement0.FirstChild.NextSibling.NextSibling.click
```

and viola! "Item 3" was selected. Thanks for the help though guys! :p